# Syntax error 'positional argument follows keyword argument' while renaming Python dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am getting the syntax error: 'positional argument follows keyword argument' while I am trying to rename some columns in a dataframe:

`cardio_df.rename(columns= {'ap_hi':'Systolic_BP'},{'ap_lo':'Diastolic_BP'},{'gluc':'glucose'},{'alco':'alcoholic'}, inplace=True)`

The error is:
cardio_df.rename(columns= {'ap_hi':'Systolic_BP'},{'ap_lo':'Diastolic_BP'},{'gluc':'glucose'},{'alco':'alcoholic'}, inplace=True)
^

> SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument

Not sure what is that I am missing.

Tried removing inplace=True but getting the same error.

Comment: You haven't specified the columns correctly.
`cardio_df.rename(columns= {'ap_hi':'Systolic_BP', 'ap_lo':'Diastolic_BP', 'gluc':'glucose', 'alco':'alcoholic'}, inplace=True)`
is the correct way to do it, by passing in a single dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

The issue in your code is that you are passing multiple dictionaries to the `columns` parameter of the `rename()` method, and Python is interpreting each dictionary as a separate positional argument.

Try passing all the column name mappings as a single dictionary:

```
cardio_df.rename(columns={'ap_hi': 'Systolic_BP', 'ap_lo': 'Diastolic_BP', 'gluc': 'glucose', 'alco': 'alcoholic'}, inplace=True)
```